# typescript: enforce strict type checking

Tags: typescript

Please see the code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20IBar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20search%3a%28any%29%20=%3E%20void;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20search%3a%28id%3astring%29%20=%3E%20void;%0D%0A%09constructor%28b%3aIBar%29%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.search%20=%20%28id%29%20=%3E%20this.searchImp%28b,%20id%29;%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20searchImp%20%28b,%20id%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b.unknownFn%28id%29;%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

```
interface IBar {
    search:(any) => void;
}

class test{
    search:(id:string) => void;
    constructor(b:IBar){
        this.search = (id) => this.searchImp(b, id);
    }

    private searchImp (b, id) {
              b.unknownFn(id);
    }
}
```

using `b.unknownFn(id)` doesn't give any error. this probably because `b` inside the function is of type `any`. still, why can't the typescript compiler infer that, I passed `b` of type `IBar` in the call

`this.search = (id) => this.searchImp(b, id);`

is it to make any javascript work with typescript?

I am porting a JS app to typescript. is there anyway to make the compiler detect these errors (during coding as I may not want to type annotate all function parameter, at least initially as I just copy over the code), so I can correct during compilation. using `noImplicitAny` detects I used `any`, still why can't it detect error based on the type passed?

Comment: For reference, can you name a language that does this? It would be incredibly computationally intensive, probably impractically so.

Comment: thanks Ryan. I didn't think about the practicality of it. also, other static languages won't allow the definition without proper typing, so never had a case it to infer and I just didn't think about the context. Anyway, greatly helped by the language and `noImplicitAny` switch. thanks for your team's work.

Comment: @Ryan Haskell does this. In fact, any statically compiled language which has truly generic functions with type inference does this. It’s not computationally intensive either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `searchImp` without any argument type annotations is just short-hand for

```
private searchImp (b : any, id : any) {
          b.unknownFn(id);
}
```

So you are saying that this method accepts anything for `b`. No further checks apply to anything of type `any`.

What you may have in mind is some form of type inference for functions without type annotations. But that is not how TypeScript works -- there is no inference, only implicit type `any`.

Comment: thanks. the disappoint thing is, typescript is compile time artifact, and still no way to detect a blatant error. Any rationale for such a decision? would it be considered in the future?

Comment: @bsr, short answer is that useful type inference for a chaotic language like JavaScript is pretty much a lost cause. Also, introducing it would likely break too much existing JavaScript code out there, which TypeScript wants to smoothly allow using.

Answer (score 0):

```
private searchImp (b:IBar, id) {
          b.unknownFn(id);
}
```

This should get you the red line, unless you specify the type of parameter for your function, it'll be treated as `any` I believe.

[Updated code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20IBar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20search%3a%28any%29%20=%3E%20void;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20search%3a%28id%3astring%29%20=%3E%20void;%0D%0A%09constructor%28b%3aIBar%29%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.search%20=%20%28id%29%20=%3E%20this.searchImp%28b,%20id%29;%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20searchImp%20%28b%3aIBar,%20id%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b.unknownFn%28id%29;%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: I understand that, and stated it in the question. but the qn is why can't the compiler see this error as I clearly pass a type of IBar.

Comment: because the compiler does not know this is the only place you'll call that function from and it has no way of knowing. It's your responsibility to specify the type you expect. The default behaviour of JS is usually respected in TS, and this is the default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript type inference does not occur based on usage. It is based on declaration. Eg. both `foo` and `arg` are any. However bar takes 1 argument and returns nothing is inferred from declaration.

```
// declaration
var foo; 
// usage 
foo = 123;
foo = 'asdf';


// declaration
function bar(arg){}
// usage 
bar(123);
bar('asdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have not unchecked the box "Allow implicit 'any' types" in the project's properties under the Typescript tab. This would have given you the red squiggles before even doing what Andreas suggested (adding explicit argument types).